# Rotate image in android

Tags: android

I want rotate image in both the ways Clockwise as well as Anti clock wise.
I had try but not rotate image both the way,
 so plz give me solution for my problem if you know..

Thanks in Advance.................///

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099652/custom-rotating-of-an-image-view

Answer (score 6):

Use the code below

```
public class Rotateimage extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
          // or just load a resource from the res/drawable directory:
          Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.flo);

          // find the width and height of the screen:
          Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
          int x = d.getWidth();
          int y = d.getHeight();

          // get a reference to the ImageView component that will display the image:
          ImageView img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

          // scale it to fit the screen, x and y swapped because my image is wider than it is tall
          Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, y, x, true);

          // create a matrix object
          Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

          matrix.postRotate(45, 90, 180);

          // create a new bitmap from the original using the matrix to transform the result
          Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap , 0, 0, scaledBitmap .getWidth(), scaledBitmap .getHeight(), matrix, true);
                // display the rotated bitmap
          img1.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the base code to load a bitmap and rotate it left or right:

```
// Load a bitmap from a drawable, make sure this drawable exists in your project
Bitmap sprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
        R.drawable.ic_launcher);

// Create two matrices that will be used to rotate the bitmap
Matrix rotateRight = new Matrix();
Matrix rotateLeft = new Matrix();

// Set the matrices with the desired rotation 90 or -90 degrees
rotateRight.preRotate(90);
rotateLeft.preRotate(-90);

// Create bitmaps based on the loaded bitmap 'sprite' and apply one of
// the rotation matrices
Bitmap rSprite = Bitmap.createBitmap(sprite, 0, 0,
        sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight(), rotateRight, true);
Bitmap lSprite = Bitmap.createBitmap(sprite, 0, 0,
        sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight(), rotateLeft, true);
```

Now go and use rSprite and lSprite.

Here is a full sample that actually draws the bitmaps to screen:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new drawView(this));
    }

    private class drawView extends View{
        public drawView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            // Load a bitmap from a drawable, make sure this drawable exists in your project
            Bitmap sprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            // Create two matrices that will be used to rotate the bitmap
            Matrix rotateRight = new Matrix();
            Matrix rotateLeft = new Matrix();

            // Set the matrices with the desired rotation 90 or -90 degrees
            rotateRight.preRotate(90);
            rotateLeft.preRotate(-90);

            // Create bitmaps based on the loaded bitmap 'sprite' and apply one of
            // the rotation matrices
            Bitmap rSprite = Bitmap.createBitmap(sprite, 0, 0,
                    sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight(), rotateRight, true);
            Bitmap lSprite = Bitmap.createBitmap(sprite, 0, 0,
                    sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight(), rotateLeft, true);

            //Draw the first unrotated sprite at the top left of the screen
            canvas.drawBitmap(sprite, 0, 0, null);

            //Draw the rotated right sprite on the 2nd row
            canvas.drawBitmap(rSprite, 0, sprite.getHeight() + 5, null);

            //Draw the rotated left sprite on the 3rd row
            canvas.drawBitmap(lSprite, 0, sprite.getHeight() * 2 + 5, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code hope it will be helpful...
you must have to write this method to do rotate operation

```
public void paintFromCenter(float angle, Canvas c) {
    Bitmap b = sprite;
    Bitmap h = b;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle, h.getWidth() / 2, h.getHeight());
    matrix.postTranslate(getX(), getY());
    // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, new Paint());
    Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(h, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight,
            matrix, true);
    c.drawBitmap(h, matrix, null);
}
```

in your program you have to write onTouchEvent() method

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        edX = (int) event.getX();
        edY = (int) event.getY();
        if ((edX > objectSprite.getX()
                && edX < objectSprite.getX() + objectSprite.getWidth()
                && edY > objectSprite.getY() && edY < objectSprite.getY()
                + objectSprite.getHeight())) {
        }
    }
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        emX = (int) event.getX();
        emY = (int) event.getY();
        if (edX < emX && angle <= 90) {
            update(canvas);
            CHAR = 'D';
        } else if (edX > emX && angle > 0) {
            update(canvas);
            CHAR = 'U';
        }
        if (edY < emY && angle <= 90) {
            update(canvas);
            CHAR = 'L';
        } else if (edY > emY && angle >= 0) {
            update(canvas);
            CHAR = 'R';
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and you have to create update() method to rotate your angle on touch event angle can be define as your choice. Initially i have declare

```
int angle=1;
public void update(Canvas canvas) {
    switch (CHAR) {
    case 'D':
        angle += 1;
        break;
    case 'U':
        angle -= 1;

        break;
    case 'R':
        angle -= 1;
        break;
    case 'L':
        angle += 1;
        break;
    }

}
```

Now you have to draw your object in draw() method like this

```
public void draw() {
  objectSprite.paintFromCenter(angle, canvas);  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add this simple code to your button

```
            imVCature_pic.setRotation(imVCature_pic.getRotation() + 90);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.preRotate(angle);///in degree
Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBmp, 0, 0, modWidth, modHeight, mat, true);
        //originalBmp -> original img as bitmap
         //modHeight -> new height
        //modWidth -> new width
```

use the above code.

Comment: Your answer is not a solution for this problem. It just guide how to rotate image using Matrix.