# Android native camera orientation

Tags: android, image, orientation, native, android-camera

I am developing an application to take photos using android native camera. The orientation of the photo has been changed with some phones (Google Nexus S and samsung galaxy s2). I know the orientation can be changed programatically after taking photo.

**But how can I correct the orientation when saving photo first time? (due to a security reason of my application I cannot do any changes to a photo after saving)**

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389613/rotate-image-in-android