# Custom Rotating of an image view

Tags: android, user-interface

imageView.SetRotation(theta) centerize the view around the pivot point and rotates the image around this pivot by theta degrees, thats nice, but how can i rotate an image view without first centerizing it around this pivot?

to clearify my question, imagine a board and an image on it, what setRotation does is sticking a pin in the middle of this image and rotate it then, what i want is to pick a pivot - say image's bottom left stick a pin there and then rotate it.

hopefully my question is clear, and solveable!

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a new pivot point using:

```
setPivotY(float pivotY);
setPivotX(float pivotX);
```

After that, the rotation will be made using the new pivot point set by the above methods.

--EDITED--

I used this method to add a `ImageView` to my layout.

```
private ImageView addImageView(RelativeLayout mainLayout, int x, int y, int width, int height, OnClickListener onClickListener){
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.height = height;
    params.width = width;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_red));
    params.leftMargin = x - width/2;
    params.topMargin = y - height/2;
    imageView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    mainLayout.addView(imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```

I called the method with this parameters:

```
    ImageView imageView;

    imageView = addImageView(mainLayout, 200, 300, 200, 200, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.setPivotX(200);
            imageView.setPivotY(200);
            imageView.setRotation(45);
        }
    });
```

Finally, you just click on the image, and the image rotates 45 degrees.

regards

Comment: it will first centerize the whole image around this pivot and that is what i dont want..

Comment: No it doesn't. It rotate all the image arround this pivot point (without centering it). Its what documentation says, and for the sake of correcteness, I've confirmed it before answering you.

Comment: @Luis Can you provide example that you've used to check that `setPivotX` and `setPivotY` work as expected?